# How to classify text with scikit's SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk, text-classification

I have a text classification task. By now i only tagged a corpus and extracted some features in a bigram format (i.e `bigram = [('word', 'word'),...,('word', 'word')]`. I would like to classify some text, as i understand SVM algorithm only can receive vectors in orther to classify, so i use some vectorizer in scikit as follows:

```
bigram = [ [('load', 'superior')
             ('point', 'medium'), ('color', 'white'),
             ('the load', 'tower')]]

fh = FeatureHasher(input_type='string')

X = fh.transform(((' '.join(x) for x in sample)
                  for sample in bigram))
print X
```

the output is a sparse matrix:

```
  (0, 226456)   -1.0
  (0, 607603)   -1.0
  (0, 668514)   1.0
  (0, 715910)   -1.0
```

How can i use the previous sparse matrix  `X` to classify with [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC)?, assuming that i have 2 classes and a train and test sets.

Comment: Every document should be a sparse vector in your matrix... libSVM expects your data to be sparse vectors... so what is your question, have you actually tried anything?

Comment: my question is how can i use the sparse matrix `X` to classify?... what's not clear?...

Comment: Sparse matrix = collection of sparse vectors. libSVM preferred input format: collection of sparse vectors. Just think outside of the "everything is a matrix" box.

Comment: Decompose your matrix into vectors. Use these vectors as features for classification. Vectors could simply be columns from the matrix

Comment: You just need labels ``y`` and then you can use ``SVC().fit(X, y)``. Not sure where the issue is.

Comment: the issue is that i would see and example on text classification using svm i review the once that scikit's documentation but still can´t understand how to use it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your matrix  is just a list of feature vectors for the documents in your corpus. Use these vectors as features for classification.  You just need classification labels y and then you can use SVC().fit(X, y).

But... the way that you have asked this makes me think that maybe you don't have any classification labels.  In this case, I think you want to be doing clustering rather than classification.  You could use one of the clustering algorithms to do this.  I suggest sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans to start.  You can then output the top 5-10 words for each cluster and form labels from those.

Comment: Thanks, in fact i have the tags and i all ready classify them in an unsupervised way. Now i would like to classify them with a supervised aproach. What could be the best aproach to present such labels to a scikit classifier?.

Comment: The 'y' in 'SVC().fit(X, y)' are the labels.  You just pass them to the classifier when you are fitting.  If you don't have all of the labels in place then you more likely want a [semi-supervised learning procedure](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html) i.e. label propagation.

Comment: Notice that as of now LabelSpreading doesn't work with sparse data